# How can I show and hide correctly a text column when I change tabs in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, hide, show

I use extjs 3.4. I need hide and show a text column that is in a form when I change of tab.

Code that I want hide and show:

```
{

    columnWidth:0.3,
    layout: 'form',
    id: 'id_siempre',
    name : 'id_siempre',

    items :[{ 
           xtype: 'tbtext', 
           text: '100% &nbsp  :  &nbsp SIEMPRE',
           style:'font-weight:bold;color:red'
          }]

    }
```

The original show this text: "SIEMPRE":

[img with "SIEMPRE"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukpmX.jpg)

In the first tab ("Evaluacion de metas") I use:

```
Ext.getCmp('id_siempre').hide();
```

And hide the text: "SIEMPRE":

[img without hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOq2.jpg)

I use this code if I change of tab "Evaluacion de competencias institucionales":

```
Ext.getCmp('id_siempre').show();
```

But is still hidden and I don't why

I tried it with an alert and it works when changing tabs, but hiding and showing  no

sorry by my english

This is my tab:

```
var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
activeTab: 0,
height : 380,

items: [{   
            xtype : "panel",
            title : "Evaluación de metas",
            id    : "id_tab_metas",
            items : [grid_metas],


            },{
            xtype : "panel",
            title : "Evaluación de competencias institucionales",
            id    : "id_tab_competencias",
            items : [grid_competencias],


            },{
            xtype : "panel",
            title : "Bitácora de seguimiento",
            id    : "id_tab_bitacora",
            items : [grid_bitacora]

       }],

       listeners: {

            'tabchange': function(tabPanel, tab) {


                if(tab.id == 'id_tab_metas'){

                  Ext.getCmp('id_siempre').hide();                     

                } else if (tab.id == 'id_tab_competencias'){

                  Ext.getCmp('id_siempre').show();


                } 


            }
        }


});
```